# Non Repeating Random Numbers Array Java, for/do/while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, random, while-loop

Hey guys I need help with this project I'm working on, I want to limit the things I use to for loops and do/while loops. I've been working on it a while and I am still confused with what I am doing. Here is what I have so far.

```
public class Array2
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array1= new int[10];
    int x=0;
    int num=0;
    do
    {
        for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
        {
            int j= 2 + (int)(Math.random() * (99-1));
            if(i==0)
            {
                array1[i]=j;
            }
            else
            {
                if(j==array1[i-1])
                {
                x++;

                }
                else
                    array1[i]=j;    
            }
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
            num++;

        }
    }while(x==0&&num<array1.length);


}
```

I understand that this code does not work, I am looking for a solution so that when x is set equal to 1 that it just sets j equal to a different random number and checks again if it is a repeating number or not. I also want to know how to check j for a repeating number instead of doing if(j==array1[i-1] because that only checks the previous array slot. Please help!

Edit:
My main question right now is how to check if j is equal to any of the numbers in array1, right now I have if(j==array1[i-1]) but that only checks the previous slot. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to add that I am trying to make a 10 number Non Repeating Array of numbers 1-100.

Comment: The normal way to do this to shuffle the values 1 to 100 and take the first 10. i.e. the first is to do something completely different. Your randomizer does 2 - 100.

Comment: @Tom `nextInt()` is not a `Math` method, its on the `Random` class, and it's an instance method

Comment: @Tom: 99-1 is 98, not 100 ? And why +1 ?

Comment: @drewmoore Right, I overlooked that `Math` :(.

Comment: Yeah Math.nextInt(100) + 1; is better thanks but how would I make sure the loop repeats when x is set to 1 am I in the right direction?

Comment: @NewbCoder1 `do { ...  } while (x==1)` ?

Comment: Nevermind Math.nextInt isn't randomized

Comment: @Charlie If it would be `Random` and not `Math`: `#nextInt(100)` generates values between `0` and `99`. To shift that "range" to `1-100`, you can add `1` to the generated number.

Comment: @NewbCoder1 Should be `Random.getRandom().nextInt(100)+1`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to solve your *main problem* to generate a sequence of `10` distinct numbers between `1` and `100`, use Java 8 and don't reinvent the wheel

```
final Collection<Integer> intList = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100) // generate an infinite list of numbers between 1 and 100
    .distinct() // avoid duplicates in that list
    .limit(10) // take only 10 numbers from that list
    .boxed() // cast them to Integer
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect them in a Collection<Integer>
```

If it should still be an array, then add this line:

```
Integer[] intArray = intList.toArray(new Integer[intList.size()]);
```

**ADDITION**

If you want a solution, which is not as simple as the example above, but may be more easy to grasp, think about this:

1: Just generate a list with the numbers of 1 to 100, so there is each number just once.

```
final List<Integer> baseIntegers = new ArrayList<>(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  baseIntegers.add(i + 1); // to get 1 to 100
}
```

The second thing you should do is, shuffling the list, so you get a random order for them.

```
Collections.shuffle(baseIntegers);
```

The last step is to take just the amount of elements you need, in your case 10:

```
final int numbersToExtract = 10;
final int[] finalArray = new int[numbersToExtract];
for (int i = 0; i < numbersToExtract; i++) {
  finalArray[i] = baseIntegers.get(i);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP (NewbCoder1) needs some explanation here (As I don't get it aswell, and I've coded for a long time)

Comment: I added some comments to explain it a bit.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to coding and I want to stray from using things I don't understand, is there a solution pertaining to what I know at the moment?

Comment: @Charlie how sould I interpret `coding for a long time` by a 15 years old programmer? @NewbCoder1 Yes, I will add it to my answer in a minute

Comment: @Chasmo Whew, I guess about 7 years by now. I grew up with Java. I've succesfully managed to code and run my own (HTML-like) protocol between multi-threaded servers and clients.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the inconvenience XD

Comment: @Charlie nice job, keep going! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For a 10 number Non Repeating Array of numbers 1-100, I would use [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) and a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (because it preserves insertion order and prevents duplicates) and something like,

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
Random rand = new Random();
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
while (set.size() < arr.length) {
    set.add(rand.nextInt(100) + 1);
}
// Copy the Set to the array.
int pos = 0;
for (Integer v : set) {
    arr[pos++] = v;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments, start by writing a `contains` method to loop through the array from the left to a given index on the right looking for a value like

```
private static boolean contains(int[] arr, int v, int pos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use that to make sure you don't enter the same value more then once in the array call `contains` like

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
Random rand = new Random();
int pos = 0;
while (pos < arr.length) {
    int val = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if (!contains(arr, val, pos)) {
        arr[pos++] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I'm in a high school computer science class I don't know anything about a LinkedHashSet. I need a solution using what I know.

Comment: @NewbCoder1 For a complete explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: @NewbCoder1 Added an example using array (and a helper method). Next time, tell us all of the requirements in your question. And how can we know what you know?

Comment: Can you possibly edit my code slightly for a solution or is it that inefficient and bad XD. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you asked for, and it will take more than a "slight" edit to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an array, say of 10 non-repeating numbers from 1-100 just do this.

1. Create ArrayList with 100 elements. elmt[0]=1, elmt[1]=2, etc
2. Create a regular array that has space for 10 elmnta, ex. regArray[10]
3. Use random # generator to generate a number from 0-99. Use that random # and    match it to ArryList entry.  So if got 67, that would represent in "real life" 68  (elmt[67]=68).  Put that in RegArray[0].
4. REMOVE elmt[67] from Array List array.
5. get random number from 0-98.  Use that rnd number as you did before and put in RegArray[1]. REMOVE the elmt from ArrayList. REPeat this shiznt till you get 10 random numbers